# How to select <i class="icon-caret-down>

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="mainBody" class="body main-content" aria-label="(N002B) Customer overview" role="complementary" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div id="Tabs2" class="Tabs topLevel CoachView tab-content CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Tabs2" data-config="config61" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_a30ea40f_cb24_4729_a02e_25dc8e12dcab.Tabs">
        <div class="s-tabs with-drop sticky">
            <div class="p-tabs-container tabable">
                <ul class="p-tabs-ul nav-tabs">
                    <li class="p-tab-li turq-style active">
                        <li class="p-tab-li turq-style">
                            <a class="p-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Tabs2-tab1">
                                <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                                <span>Items (USD)</span>
                                <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
                            </a>
```

in above html how can i select "

I have tried the following :

1. By `.cssSelector(".icon-caret-down")`
2. Xpath `value = //*[@id='Tabs2']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a/i[2]`

it is not working..

Comment: `its not working..` what do you mean by this? getting any exceptions?

Comment: getting the message as  "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:"

Comment: are you using implicit or explicit wait?..can you paste the java code as part your question?

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Tabs2']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a/i[2]")).click();

   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: The element should be first visible in order to click it. Try using explicit wait till the element is visible in the application.

Comment: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` this can be mentioned just once at the start of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give [Explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) a try,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#Tabs2 .p-tab > .icon-caret-down"))).click();
```

The above code will wait 60 secs for the visibility of `.icon-caret-down` element.